# Share one css file across multiple websites

Tags: html, css

So this is what I'm trying to achieve: I want to share one CSS file hosted on one website of mine with two other micro sites which have certain similar components sharing the same CSS rules.

I thought this wouldn't be allowed. Otherwise, any websites can simply use any CSS files out there on the web? However, I did a test by putting the CSS tag on one of my site:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://my-other-site.com/styles.css" type="text/css">
```

and found out it's actually working. Shouldn't we have certain protection like CORS?

I looked into the header and found out the source server does not have header param like '`access-control-allow-origin: *`', but the request header does have things like:

```
sec-fetch-mode: no-cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
```

I just wonder how this work, and can I just go ahead and simply put in the same css tag across all my websites and that's it? I don't need to do anything on HTTP header?

Comment: In general `CORS` is managed by the host/domain controller. It is simply that when other domain request resources from other domain, the browser will block it. So your resource domain `CORS` might be open for other domain request. see more here   [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Answer (score 0):

Cross-origin embedding (such as CSS applied with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="…">`) is typically allowed.

You can read up more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Cross-origin_network_access